# Im reaching the field limit on elastic search but when I look in Kibana it seems like I still have a lot of room for fields

Tags: elasticsearch

Importing some admittedly large json documents in Elastic search and getting the error `Limit of total fields [1000] has been exceeded while adding new fields [447]`
When I look at the table in kibana on the index patterns page I see fields that seem to be unnecessary.
[image]

My question is it looks like a keyword field and a text field are added for the same value.
In the json it looks similar to the following

```
{
  v300_oeminfo:{
    serial_number:'2342',
    software_version: '234233'
  }
}
```

Why would two fields be dedicated to serial_number and software_version.

Comment: what version of Elasticsearch are you using? are you defining your own index templates or using dynamic ones?

Comment: Its elastic search 7.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the behavior of dynamic mapping was to assign both keyword and text to the same field.  Thats why it looked like the fields were doubling up on kibana.